# Ransack sort order scope with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a Site model with relation Notification.
The site has several notifications every day. I try to calculate the sum of notifications for a few days and want to sort the sites by this sum.

```
class Site
  has_many :notifications
  scope :sort_by_notifications_between_dates_asc, -> (start_date, end_date) { left_joins(:notifications).merge(Notification.between_dates(start_date, end_date)).order(Arel.sql("count(notifications.*) asc")) }
  scope :sort_by_notifications_between_dates_desc, -> (start_date, end_date) { left_joins(:notifications).merge(Notification.between_dates(start_date, end_date)).order(Arel.sql("count(notifications.*) desc")) } 
end

class Notification
  belongs_to :site
  scope :between_dates, -> (start_date, end_date) {where(self.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(start_date.at_beginning_of_day).and(self.arel_table[:created_at].lteq(end_date.at_end_of_day)))} 
end
```

It is possible for ransack to create a scope for sorting, but I have not found a way to pass the arguments (start_date and end_date) to this scope.

```
= sort_link(@q, :notifications_between_dates, t('.notifications_between_dates'), default_order: :desc)
```

I do not need to filter sites by date. I need to sort the sites by the sum of the notifications for the period of time. Is this even possible?

Comment: try something along those lines: `= sort_link(@q, notifications_between_dates: {start_date, end_date} ....` for `start_date` and `end_date` the actual values. Or
`= sort_link(@q, notifications_between_dates: {start_date: xxxxx, end_date: xxxx } ....`
Have nothing to test on.

Comment: sort_link don't support passing arguments via get request in s parameter. But I found half the solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found half the solution. I created ransacker with arguments

```
ransacker :notifications_between_dates, args: [:parent, :ransacker_args] do |parent, args|
start_date, end_date = args
query = <<-SQL
 COALESCE(
  (SELECT COUNT(notifications.*) 
     FROM notifications
    WHERE notifications.site_id = sites.id
      AND notifications.created_at >= '#{start_date}'
      AND notifications.created_at <= '#{end_date}' 
    GROUP BY notifications.site_id)
 ,0)
SQL
Arel.sql(query)
end
```

Then we can sort records in this way

```
q = Site.ransack(sorts: [{name: :notifications_between_dates,
                           dir: 'asc',
                ransacker_args: [Time.now-20.days,Time.now]}])
```

But looks like **sort_link** helper does not support passing ransacker_args via GET request in **s** parameter.